# hover on unordered list item causes other div element to animate unwantedly

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-animate, jquery-hover

i was working on html to show the share icons and a music player in right side sticky manner. i created the css and jquery animations for it. i am facing issue that hover on facebook icon causes animate the music player div, i don't want music player to animate on facebook hover.

below is fiddle and markup

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c9hZN/)**

```
<div class="footer">
<ul class="socialLinks">
            <li>
                <div class="sociallink">
                    <a class="fb text-color" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/princeofcool">
                        Facebook</a></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="strapper-div">
            <div class="vol-icn">
                <a class="musicPlayer" href="javascript:;"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="left" style="width: 115px; color: #fff; padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 5px;">
                <div class="marquee">
                    <span class="current-song marquee-text"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="next-btn">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://goo.gl/YuEBEo" width="25" alt=">" /></a></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.footer { position:fixed; right:0px; bottom:0px; margin-bottom:70px; z-index:9999; }
ul.socialLinks { position:relative; z-index:999; }
ul.socialLinks li { overflow:hidden; }
ul.socialLinks li div { height:30px; padding:7px; margin-right:-73px; float:right; }
ul.socialLinks li div a { display:block; height:30px; width:58px; line-height:30px; font-weight:300; padding-left:40px; padding-right:5px;  background-position: top left; background-repeat:no-repeat; }

ul.socialLinks li div a.fb, ul.mSocialLinks li a.fb { background-image:url('http://goo.gl/XmBIAZ'); }
ul.socialLinks li div:hover a.fb, ul.mSocialLinks li:hover a.fb { background-image:url('http://goo.gl/bytO8P'); }


a.musicPlayer { display:block; float:right; text-indent:-9999px; width:44px; height:33px; background-image:url('http://johnericbooth.com/2014/assets/styles/img//music.gif'); background-position: center center; background-repeat:no-repeat; 
                top: 0px; /* For IE8 and earlier */
                }
a.musicPlayer.off { background-image:url('http://goo.gl/jDoqWk');}


        .strapper-div
        {
            height: 33px;
            width: 200px;
            background: #000;
            padding-top: 7px;
            padding-bottom: 7px;
            padding-left: 1px;
            padding-right: 3px;
        }

        .vol-icn
        {
            /*background: red;*/
            width: 44px;
            height: 33px;
            float: left;
        }

        .next-btn
        {
            float: right;
            vertical-align: middle;
            padding-top: 3px;
            padding-right: 5px;
        }

        .left
        {
            float: left;
        }
```

**Jquery**

```
   $('.strapper-div').stop().animate({ marginRight: '-216px' }, 600);
```

$('ul.socialLinks>li>div').not('li.strapper-div').hover(function () {

```
    $(this).stop().animate({ marginRight: 0 }, 250, function () { });
},
function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({ marginRight: '-73px' }, 250, function () { });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `position: relative` means that the space is reserved in the parent div (`div.footer`) for the whole element; as its margin is changed, it takes more space and makes the whole footer div expand. As the other element (`div.strapper`) is anchored to the left side, it too is slidden into the view.

To remedy you can position `div.sociallink` `absolute`ly, or you can `float: right` the `div.strapper`.

Comment: thanks alot@antti setting strapper div to float left did the magic

Answer (score 1):

The div.sociallink (singluar) is increasing the width of the outer div.footer.  As .strapper-div has a negative margin, it's position is relative to the div.footer width. Thus as the div.footer width increases, the negative margin moves as well.

Seen by wrapping div.footer with a yellow border.

If you only what the .sociallink to move it will need to be positioned absolutely e.g.

```
div.sociallink { position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; }
```

But you will need to fix other parts of the HTML to make all work as nicely as you had it before. It could get quite messy so be careful with negative margins and floats and positioned absolutely.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks alot@colin for looking into my issue in question, your answer helped me too but answer from antti made it to be the final